# How to turn entire square image into trapezium

Tags: inkscape

I have the following object that I have drawn in inkscape

[image]

and I would like to turn it into a trapezium. I am trying to follow the steps online:
1) selecting the object and converting object to path
2) selecting the top corner nodes and dragging them inwards

unfortunately the whole image does not conform to this and I end up with the following

[image]

I have been trying lots of things for the past hour. "Grouping" & "ungrouping" the object beforehand and "unioning" & "combining" the path afterwards, but I can't get the final path to be treated as one object. I think I fundamentally misunderstand what is meant by all of these things, and I don't understand the difference between and object and a path really, so any help here would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks,
Adam.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Make sure that all of the objects in your image are paths (and not circles, rectangles or similar). Selecting everything and *path → object to path* should do the job.
2. *Duplicate* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>) the framing rectangle.
3. *Group* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>) everything but one of the duplicate rectangles.
4. Make a trapezium of the ungrouped rectangle.
5. Select the group and then the trapezium.
6. Apply *extensions → modify path → perspective.*

You should get what you wish. If everything is rotated, go back and rotate the rectangle before Step 4.

Comment: Wow that worked, but it rotated the contents of the group 90 degrees.

Comment: @davea0511: Please see my edit.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft i'm confused by this step: "Make a trapezium of the ungrouped rectangle." how do i do that?

Comment: @Jayen: At this point, your reactangle should be a regular path (as opposed to a special rectangle object); if not *convert selected object to path* (Ctrl+Shift+C). Then you move the individual nodes with *edit paths by nodes* (F2). To assure perfect symmetry, move the nodes using the arrow keys.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft thanks.  my problem turned out to be that my path wasn't a rectangle, but a collection of triangles.  made a rectangle and sorted it out.  thanks.

Comment: In case you have a path with dash pattern (and some width), don't forget to use "Path>Convert Outline to Path" on this path to include the individual dots or rectangles in the dash pattern into the perspective operation.