# Inkscape Transformation Matrices

Tags: inkscape, transform

I am trying to transform a rectangular shape to a trapezium as shown in the image below. In the Inkscape transform menu, there is an option to use a 2x3 matrix. However, that does not allow "3d" transformations. I think I read somewhere that the SVG specification supports larger matrices, but I cannot find much information about it. So my question is: how do you do this in Inkscape?

[image: Transform rectangle to trapezium]

Comment: For future readers: this is not a classic case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676), but it's close enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SVG transformation matrices](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) only allow for [affine transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation), i.e., something that is a combination of moving, rotating, stretching and skewing. Trapezium transformations cannot be expressed as a combination of these operations and thus they are not possible to be done with SVG transformation matrices.

However, *extensions → modify path → perspective* performs such a transformation. For details, see for example [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/65614/19174).

Comment: Ok... The first time I tried it, the shapes were sideways, and it left half of them in their original places. After unlinking all the clones, it doesn't do anything at all... I don't know what's happening.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: I am sorry, but I have no idea. Unlinking clones seems like a good idea in general, but it should not lead to nothing kappening at all.

Comment: It could be that now there are two many objects... Because it seems to do all the calculations, and takes its time over it, but then doesn't produce a result. Hmm...

Comment: I have ungrouped all of the sub-groups, and now it complains that one or other of the items selected is not a path, no matter which order I select them in.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: Try applying *Object to Path* to everything – everything must be a path.

Comment: Funny, I just came onto the site again to say "I've just tried *Object to Path* and I think it's worked". And it's just worked... except everything's still sideways.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: What exactly do yo mean by *sideways?* If it looks as if the trapezium is used for transformation but not as you wish, try to change its sequence of vertices (easiest done in the XML editor).

Comment: For future reference, your last comment solved the issue I was having.